# TcpClient throws Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "No such host is known" in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a TcpClient object `New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($Server, $Port)`
When I use a variable for $Server an exception is thrown but if I statically set the value it works...

I've tried enclosing `$Server` in quotes, Ensuring there was no whitespace `$Server.Trim()` and also confirmed `$Server` is a String

Comment: aside from using parenthesis `TcpClient($Server, $Port)` when you shouldn't `TcpClient $Server, $Port` there is nothing wrong with your statement. Besides, the error indicates that `$server` is not a valid host or you can't connect to it

Comment: Upon further analysis of my script  had the value of `$server`  encased in quotes I fixed this and now it all works

Answer (score 0):

Upon further analysis of my script had the value of $server encased in quotes.